# I can't leave pdf with webview

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, webview, viewcontroller

Does anyone know how to leave  pdf with webview

this app is done with xcode,i learn it from internet

but I got a issue, when I click a download link

it would open the file in app , but I can't go back to

previous page , I can't do anything but close app & restart

So what should I add to make app go back to previous page

here is my app ,

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite/index.php"];
    [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Is there any other ViewController in your app? How are you rendering your ViewController which loads webView ??

Comment: No,i created a simple project and do some change in viewcontroller.h & .m    also drag a webview element into this app